# Token for URL to delete a record

Tags: related-list

How to generate a confirmation token to delete a related list record?

When we delete a related list record it takes 4 parameters -

> 1) id - Record id
>
> 2) delID= Related list record id
>
> 3) retURL
>
> 4) _CONFIRMATIONTOKEN

So how can we generate this _CONFIRMATIONTOKEN?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you attempting this in Apex or another API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are in Visualforce, you can use the `URLFOR()` function in conjunction with the `$Action` global variable to generate this URL. The `URLFOR` function will automatically add the `_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN` to the end of your URL.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityTeamMember.Delete,member.Id)}">
    <apex:outputText value="Delete"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

This will generate URL's of the form:

```
https://<Instance>.salesforce.com/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp?id=<Opportunity Id>&delID=<Opportunity Team Member Id>&retURL=%2F00Q%2Fo&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=<ConfirmationToken>
```

Here is a sample Visualforce Page, called 'OpportunityTest', that shows you the Team Members for an Opportunity, and allows you to Delete them using the above strategy. I have also added in a 'retURL' parameter to the Output Link, which takes you back to the OpportunityTest page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">

<apex:sectionHeader title="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>

<apex:pageBlock title="Team Members">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityTeamMembers}" var="member">
    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR(
                $Action.OpportunityTeamMember.Delete,
                member.Id,
                [retURL='/apex/OpportunityTest?id='&opportunity.Id]
         )}">
            <apex:outputText value="Delete"/>
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!member.User.Name}"/>            
    <apex:column value="{!member.TeamMemberRole}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: I used custom logic to iterate "Opportunity Team" list on opportunity. Now i want, when user clicks on "Del"  link that record should be deleted and for that i need "confirmation token". so how can i achieve this? plz explain

Comment: what would be $Action string to delete opp team record?

Comment: Pramod, i have updated my answer above with a better example, but the `$Action` is `$Action.OpportunityTeamMember.Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on the force.com discussions... here: [Token for URL to delete a record?](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Token-for-URL-to-delete-a-record/td-p/278019)

Hope this gets you where you are going!

Comment: That post just links to another post which is a discussion of how to build a button that is similar to the standard delete button (e.g. a javascript confirm). It doesn't seem to be related to confirmation tokens at all.

Comment: I'm just new here, and trying to help... this q had been open for hours with no responses, so thought a little was better than nothing.

Comment: @dacology, thanks for getting involved! In this case, a comment would have probably been a better way to give some feedback. Since you are new, you may not have had the permission to comment yet, but now that you have some reputation, you should be able to. Always good to see new faces on the site!

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am beginning to understand and appreciate how it all works now.