# Using URLFOR to delete a CaseContactRole

Tags: related-list, actionfunction, outputlink

I readed on the post [Token for URL to delete a record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13212/token-for-url-to-delete-a-record) on how to use URLFOR, but it doesn't work in my case:

```
Error: Field $Action.CaseContactRole.Delete does not exist. Check Spelling.
```

I know based on https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_action_values.htm the Delete action is not available for CaseContactRole but it's also not documented for OpportunityTeamMember.

Do you have any idea or I will have to create a an action on a custom controller to get it working?

Thanks

Mat

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per your link the only objects which are supported by the Delete action are custom, and

`Ad group
Asset
Campaign
Campaign member
Case
Contact
Contract
Event
Google campaign
Keyword
Lead
Opportunity
Opportunity product
Product
Search phrase
SFGA version
Solution
Task
Text ad`

So you will have to create an action on a custom controller to get it to work as expected.

An alternative is to simply output a link to:

```
/setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp?delID={recordId}&retURL={wherever you want}
```